# What type of number is the next expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, nested-radicals

Which is the result for:
$\sqrt{3-\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{{9-4\sqrt{5}}}}$?

It is a natural number?

Answer (score 5):

HINT : $$9-4\sqrt 5=9-2\sqrt{20}=5+4-2\sqrt{5\cdot 4}=(\sqrt 5-\sqrt 4)^2.$$

Comment: Thanks.The final result is 1.

Comment: @Julia: You are welcome. Yes, you are correct.